# get string inside custom matching bracket

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

Getting strings inside matching brackets has been asked a lot here, but I haven't any luck applying them to the problem at hand: I'm trying to replace red text label in a LaTeX file `\red{any text}` with just `any text`. However, the problem is that `any text` may **span multiple lines**, and also **contain closing brackets**, e.g. `\red{some \ref{reference} text...}`, and the result should be `some \ref{reference} text...`

The perl one-liner

```
perl -0777 -i.bak -pe 's/\\red{([^}]*)}/\1/igs' /path/to/file.tex
```

or with python

```
from pyparsing import *

sample = "\\red{some \\ref{stuff} text}"

scanner = originalTextFor(nestedExpr('\\red{','}'))

for match in scanner.searchString(sample):
    print(match[0])
```

gives the wrong result `\red{some \ref{stuff}`. I know this can theoretically be done by counting brackets, but I'm trying to find a more elegant/clean approach.

Comment: Try `'s/\\red({((?>[^{}]+|(?1))*)})/\2/ig'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `perl`, you may match nested structures and balanced amount of parentheses. Use the following regex:

```
's/\\red({((?>[^{}]+|(?1))*)})/\2/ig'
```

It will match:

- `\\red` - a `\red` substring
- `({((?>[^{}]+|(?1))*)})` - Group 1 (technical, we will need to recurse it) capturing:

  - `{` - an open `{`
  - `((?>[^{}]+|(?1))*)` - Group 2 capturing 1+ chars other than `{` and `}` (with `[^{}]+`) or the whole Group 1 pattern (with the `(?1)` [subroutine call](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html))
  - `}` - a close `}`

The match is replaced with the `\2` backreference, Group 2 contents.

You do not need `s` modifier, since there is no dot in the pattern.

See [an online text](http://ideone.com/Xl6sC1) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kzxJws/1).